# Django problem: views.py called twice, variables overridden

Tags: python, django, redirect, server

I use django to process users data in json recieved thru typeform's api(a google forms-like service). After submitting their typeforms, users are redirected to my django server which passes processed data to a link of a landing page where users' scores are displayed.

This worked for a while, but after a lot of back and forth with different verisons of my algorithm, the views.py function is called twice. What's even weirder - the variables get overridden, which shouldnt be possible concering the sctructure of my code. Each score in the list below shouldn't be higher than 40, but it gets multiplied. After I reset the server it's good again but only for one GET request, then it gets messy again regardless whether its the same user's email(used for identifying his/hers submit data) or a different one. This is how it looks in my console:

```
Django version 3.0.3, using settings 'demo_server.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.

# First request:

user's scores: [['A', 30], ['R', 24], ['E', 20], ['I', 16], ['S', 16], ['C', 14]]
{correct link}
[04/May/2020 15:01:23] "GET /typeform/dan@hiry.pl HTTP/1.1" 302 0

# Second request:

user's scores: [['A', 100], ['R', 82], ['E', 70], ['I', 58], ['S', 58], ['C', 52]]
(i've added a few lines to identify when the scores are to high to redirect users to an error page)

{error page link}
[04/May/2020 15:01:26] "GET /typeform/dan@hiry.pl HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[04/May/2020 15:01:26] "GET /typeform/home HTTP/1.1" 200 42

# as you can see above, there are two requests happening the same second instead of one
```

The only threads I found concering this issue were either pretty old and focused on django's forms which I haven't so far used(I've tried to make my script as simple as I could) and/or completely unresovled. I've tried to inhibit this overriding at least the redirect link in the script(with `quit()` for example) but nothing worked.

Thanks in advance and have a good day you all :)

Edit 1: as requested, here's how my views.py look:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import redirect
import time
import json
import requests

def typeform_redirect(request, tmail='kosma@hiry.pl'):
    # here the correct link for the user with a matching email is generated
    print(link)
    response = redirect(link)
    return response
```

Comment: could you provide the code on your views, and urls?

Comment: @arianhf i'm afraid i can't share it all since it's a company intellectual property + the code on my views.py is around 800 lines(i suppose it's not the greatest solution to have such long functions in views.py but i needed an ad-hoc way to make it worked and it did pretty well until recently), little to no of which could be connected to this issue i think. i've edited the post to include at least its essential structure tho.

Comment: Just to be sure, In the typeform setting you are redirecting the user to `/typeform/{email_answered_in_the_typeform}` ?

Does the double loading only happen after a redirect from typeform? or also when you open manually the URL?

Comment: @NicolasGrenié 1) yes indeed. 2) it happens when redirected from typeform as well as when the url is entered manually.

Comment: created a new django project and the problem persists so i'm 95% positive it's about views.py

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Problem solved! Did this a while ago and didn't catch a moment to post it here but it was all most likely due to the fact that i've accidentally created an instance of a `User` class before `def typeform_redirect()` and/or another small twitch like that. I'll post when I find the second one cause I explained it to a friend in a sms some time ago.